# Can you introduce a direct quotation with "that" and not accommodate conjugation and pronouns?

Tags: quotations, indirect-speech

I've heard this many times recently in public, copy-edited discourse, where I don't expect to find grammatical errors, but it doesn't sound right to me. Let's say my mom says to me, "I want you to clean your room." I can report what she said with a direct quotation:

> My mom said, "I want you to clean your room."

Or I can report it indirectly:

> My mom said that she wanted me to clean my room.

My question is, can you introduce a direct quote with "that" without accommodating it? e.g.,

> My mom said that "I want you to clean your room."

Is this acceptable? This sounds wrong to me since "that" makes it sound indirect, and that I, the speaker (not my mom), want my listener (not me) to clean their room. I thought it would need to be like this to be correct:

> My mom said that "[she] want[ed] me to clean [my] room."

(of course, the brevity of this example quote hardly justifies this, but ignore that)

Comment: Though partial quotes such as << The President said that the Government "want all workers to receive a realistic wage" >> where the grammar in the report tag and the verbatim part-quote mesh rarely cause a knee-jerk reaction nowadays, I'd consider your example unacceptable (and your correction unacceptably convoluted as per Grice's Fourth Maxim :) ) So << *The President said that he "w/Wants all workers to receive a realistic wage" >> (unless the President actually spoke like Popeye, "We wants all ...").

Comment: There is not need for a that. My mother said she wanted me to clean my room. When the subject of the main clause and the subordinate clause are  the same, you can skip the that.

Comment: Where you will see quotes in reported speech is around individual words or phrases to indicate (1) the speaker used those exact words and (2) that you probably would not have chosen those words yourself. To steal the example from @EdwinAshworth - "The President said that he wants all workers to receive a 'realistic' wage." This means that I am not endorsing the President's judgement that a particular wage is realistic (either because I disagree or because I'm trying to display a degree of journalistic impartiality).

Comment: It would be possible to write: *My mother said this: "Tidy your room!"* But if you use *that* it's more confusing because of the additional functions *that* can have.

Answer (score 1):

'That' introduces a subordinate clause, and more specifically in instances such as 'she knew that' or 'I believed that' or 'he thought that' introduces indirect discourse.

Indirect discourse has its rules such as the shifting of tense. For example
direct: She said, "I am ready."
indirect: She said that she was ready.
present tense --> past tense
direct:  John said, "I will go."
indirect:  John said (that) he would go.
future tense --> conditional tense

So, no. In the last example, it is impossible to say: John said that "I will go."

Some links for indirect discourse:
https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-indirect-speech-1691058
https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fcomm.2020.606616/full